# SimpleXMLElement->asXML() outputting bad string

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a php function that converts an object hierarchy to xml. asXML is not working as expected. Can anybody tell me why this:

```
            $oReportXML = new SimpleXMLElement("<report></report>");
    $oReportXML->addChild('details');
    $oReportXML->addChild('configuration');
    $oReportXML->addChild('datasources');
    $oReportXML->addChild('styles');
    $oReportXML->addChild('classes');
    $oReportXML->addChild('tables');

    $oReportXML->details->addChild('author',$this->iAuthor);
    $oReportXML->details->addChild('date_created',$this->iDateCreated);
    $oReportXML->details->addChild('date_modified',$this->iLastModifiedDate);
    $oReportXML->details->addChild('modified_by',$this->iLastModifiedBy);
    $oReportXML->details->addChild('id',$this->iReportID);
    print_r($this);
    print "<p>".$oReportXML->asXML()."</p>";
```

would output this:

```
Report Object ( [iAuthor] => 1 [iDateCreated] => 11 [iLastModifiedDate] => 1330435328 [iLastModifiedBy] => 1378 [iReportID] => 0 [sSubject] => sSubject [iCategory] => iCategory [sKeywords] => sKeywords [sDescription] => sDescription [sTitle] => IGNORE_ME [aTables] => Array ( ) [aClasses] => Array ( ) [aDataSources] => Array ( ) [aStyles] => Array ( ) [oParent:private] => )

111133043532813780
```

Comment: Quoted code works well on my PHP.

Comment: what you using to check output? may be your browser just hidiing tags?

Comment: try new DomDocument(); in php ,, that is much easy than this

Comment: I second @SamArulRaj -- SimpleXML is best suited for reading XML. If you need to actually edit I would highly recommend using `DOM` instead.

Comment: perhaps you can use <pre></pre> instead of <p></p> to visualize your xml document

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 print "<p>".htmlentities ($oReportXML->asXML())."</p>";
```

I think if you look into the source the xml is in there, but since you're looking it via browser which happens to dismiss all the tags, you're seeing only text nodes.

Comment: This worked for me, but it returns the XML in one line string. How do I show it in proper XML form? i.e. each node in its own line?
Thanx

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking the output in the browser, you will see only the values, as browsers do not visualize tags. Look at source code, or add header('Content-type:text/xml'); to tell the browser it should display XML